# How to detect when a bluetooth device is connected in python

Tags: python, bluetooth

I  am looking for a way to detect whenever a device is paired with another via bluetooth using python.

For example:

```
if (device has been added):
  print("Device has been connected")
```

Ideally this could be a scan, so while a python script is running:

```
while (no devices connected)
   print("There are no devices connected")
end while
print("device connected.)
```

Comment: Did you try googling "python bluetooth"?

Comment: What have you tried so far and why didn't it work?

Comment: I have googled and cannot find a way to see if a device is connected, and can only find nearby devices.